# Fetching data from database to bar graph with php

Tags: php, json, graph

I have a graph with this kind of data format

data:[station_id1,station_id2,station_id3]    x axis
date:[total_station1,total_station2,total_station3]  y axis

however i want to fetch the data from my database table which have list of all the station_id and their corresponding data. i want to all the distinct station id for x axis and correspondence total sum of each id for y axis.

below is my code

```
data: [<?php
$q = "SELECT DISTINCT  outletid,amount FROM " . TBL_SALES_LOGS;
$result = $database->query($q);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // $outletname = $row['title'];
    $outlet_id = $row['outletid'];
    $amount = $row['amount'];
    ?>
    <?php echo " $outlet_id"; ?>,
<?php } ?> ]

data: [<?php
$qsum3 = "SELECT  SUM(amount) AS totalsum FROM " . TBL_SALES_LOGS . " WHERE outletid ='$outlet_id' and fueltype='AGO'";
$qresult3 = $database->query($qsum3);
while ($rowq3 = $qresult3->fetch_assoc()) {
    $tot3 = $rowq3['totalsum'];
    ?>'<?php echo $tot3; ?>',<?php } ?>]
```

After running it, the output is:

data: [ 520718, 567329, ] data: ['5000',]

and what i want is data 1 to be distinct station id and data2 should be sum of each distinct station id to correspond with data1

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below, this might solve your problem:

```
<?php
$q = "SELECT DISTINCT  outletid,amount FROM " . TBL_SALES_LOGS;
$result = $database->query($q);
$outlets = [];
?>
data: [<?php
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // $outletname = $row['title'];
    $outlet_id = $row['outletid'];
    $outlets[] = $row['outletid'];
    $amount = $row['amount'];
    ?>
    <?php echo $outlet_id; ?>,
<?php } ?> ]

data: [<?php
$outlet = implode("','", $outlets);
$qsum3 = "SELECT  outletid, SUM(amount) AS totalsum FROM " . TBL_SALES_LOGS . " WHERE outletid IN ('{$outlet}') and fueltype='AGO' group by `outletid`";
$qresult3 = $database->query($qsum3);
while ($rowq3 = $qresult3->fetch_assoc()) {
    $tot3 = $rowq3['totalsum'];
    ?>'<?php echo $tot3; ?>',<?php } ?>]
```

This uses an array of outlets to get data against them.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, i willlook into it, after running the code. This is my result  data: [ 520718, 520718, 567329, ] data: ['26400'] and what is still not what i want

Comment: Thanks, its still giving me this data: [ 520718, 520718, 567329, ] data: ['23000',] and first data is suppose to be distince which should also give corresponding values on second data

Comment: I have tweaked the code a bit more, try again. Also, try `var_dump($outlets)` at the end and provide its output, if it still does not work.

Comment: Thanks, it kinda work. data: [ 520718, 520718, 567329, ] data: ['2000','21000',]   just that the first data is not distinct

Comment: @Ademaintain Try running this query `$q = "SELECT DISTINCT  outletid,amount FROM " . TBL_SALES_LOGS;` Directly, using PHPMyAdmin or something, and check if it is providing distinct results or not.

Comment: @Ademaintain Or try changing the query to: 

`$q = "SELECT  outletid, amount FROM " . TBL_SALES_LOGS . 'GROUP BY outletid';`

Comment: adding amount to the query doesnt give disntinct value, but i eventually used $q = "SELECT DISTINCT outletid,amount FROM " which now gave a distinct value and it works well. Thanks

Comment: @Ademaintain If my solution worked, then please upvote and accept the answer. Thank you